# How to sort file with temporary locale in shell script?

Tags: shell, sorting, unicode, chinese-locale

I need to sort some files containing Chinese strings using `zh_CN.utf8` while my system is in `en_US.utf8`.

For instance I have `test.csv` :

```
4001,动词,動詞,dong4ci2
4000,不然,不然,bu4ran2
3999,规格,規格,gui1ge2
3998,抽出,抽出,chou1chu1
3997,浮水印,浮水印,fu2shui3yin4
3996,拖曳與贴上,拖曳與貼上,tuo1ye4yu3tie1shang4
3995,云端运算,雲端運算,yun2duan1yun4suan4
3994,字集,字集,zi4ji2
3993,内码,內碼,nei4ma3
3992,兼容,兼容,jian1rong2
```

I'm trying to sort by `simplified chinese`, *i.e.* 2nd field, as follow:

```
sort -t ',' -d -k 2 test.csv
```

So how would I specify a locale only for the `sort` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `LC_ALL` temporarily like this:

```
LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf8 sort -t ',' -d -k 2 test.csv
```